# How pass slash "\" value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c

I'm trying to pass slash keyword "\" by using javascript. But not taking the slash in text field.

Example:

```js
document.getElementById("demo1").value = "welcome\"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h2>JavaScript String Properties</h2>
  <p>The length property returns the length of a string:</p>
  Username : <input id="demo1" />
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

JavaScript String Properties

The length property returns the length of a string:

Username :    [It's empty field]

How to pass the "welcome\".

Could please help me how I will get below output.

Username : welcome\

Comment: What relevance do `ios` or `objective-c` or `html` tags have?

Comment: Welcome to `C` world.

Answer (score 2):

Just append one more `\` to escape the string

```js
document.getElementById("demo1").value = "welcome\\";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h2>JavaScript String Properties</h2>
  <p>The length property returns the length of a string:</p>
  Username : <input id="demo1" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`\` (Escape character)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) is a reserved character and it has a special meaning. You have to escape with another `\` to evaluate that literally:

```html
<h2>JavaScript String Properties</h2>
<p>The length property returns the length of a string:</p>
Username : <input id="demo1"/>

<script>
  document.getElementById("demo1").value = "welcome\\"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an escape character(prepend it with a backslash) to get the expected result.

More precisely, it should be

```
"welcome\\"



document.getElementById("demo1").value = "welcome\\"
```